# How can I get the session stored in a Ember-Simple-Auth session?

Tags: json, session, authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'm using ember-simple-auth to manage my app authentication.

I have implemented my own authenticator, authorizer and adapter.

### Source code

### *Authenticator*

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base';

export default Base.extend({

  tokenEndpoint: 'http://localhost:9000/0/auth/',

  restore: function(data) {
    console.log("restore");
    console.log(data);
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      if (!Ember.isEmpty(data.token)) {
        resolve(data);
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  },

  authenticate: function(options) {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Ember.$.ajax({
        url: this.tokenEndpoint + options.method,
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(options.data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json'
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log("OK!");
        console.log(response);
        Ember.run(function() {
          console.log("resolve: "+response.data.encodedToken);
          resolve({
            token: response.data.encodedToken
          });
        });

      }, function(xhr, status, error) {
        var response = xhr.responseText;
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(response);
        Ember.run(function() {
          reject(response);
        });
      });
    });
  },

  invalidate: function() {
    console.log('invalidate...');
    //return Ember.RSVP.resolve();

    Ember.$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: this.tokenEndpoint + 'logout',
      }).then(() => {
        resolve(true);
      }, () => {
        reject();
      });
  }
});
```

### *Authorizer*

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authorizers/base';

export default Base.extend({
  authorize: function(jqXHR, requestOptions) {
          console.log(requestOptions);
          console.log("---- Authorize ----");
          var accessToken = this.get('session.content.secure.token');
          console.log(this.get('session'));
          if (this.get('session.isAuthenticated') && !Ember.isEmpty(accessToken)) {
              jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', accessToken);
          }
      }
});
```

### *Adapter*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

import JSONAPIAdapter from 'ember-data/adapters/json-api';

import singularize from 'ember-inflector';

export default JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  namespace: '0',
  host: 'http://localhost:9000',
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
  headers: Ember.computed('session.token', function() {
    console.log("Sending header...");
    return {
      'Authorization': 'MYTOKEN'
    };
  }),

  pathForType: function(type) {
    return Ember.String.underscore(type);
    //return singularize(type);
  },

});
```

## Questions

I would like to know how to get the stored token in the authentication process, inside the adapter to inject the encoded token in the header `Authorization`.

And another question, when is it called the authorizer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using ESA 1.0 or later. You don't get the `jqXHR` in the authorizer's `authorize` method then but the session data along with a callback instead.

Check the docs for the [`DataAdapterMixin`](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/DataAdapterMixin.html) and [`BaseAuthorizer`](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/BaseAuthorizer.html) as well as the [README](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#implementing-a-custom-authorizer) for more info.